# How to read data from Datatable in primefaces jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to JSF and Primefaces. I want to get all data from a datatable like row by row. My datatable contains dropdown values as columns which can be selected by end user. I want to get all these data on a command button click so that I can save it into database. Please somebody help.

```
    <p:dataTable  id="pan1tab1" rowIndexVar="index1" rendered="#{step1Bean.showPanel1}" var="car" value="#{dtEditView.table1}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars1" >

   <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onCellEdit}" update=":form:dialogue" />

   <p:column headerText="Empty" id="Empty1">
          <p:cellEditor>
              <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.tab1prodLine}" /></f:facet>
              <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.tab1prodLine}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>
          </p:cellEditor>
      </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="1" id="col11">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.tab1column1}" /></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
               <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.tab1column1}" style="width:100%">
                   <f:selectItems value="#{dtEditView.tab1cols1}" var="man" itemLabel="#{man}" itemValue="#{man}" />
               </h:selectOneMenu>
           </f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="2" id="col12">
       <p:cellEditor>
           <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.tab1column2}" /></f:facet>
           <f:facet name="input">
               <h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.tab1column2}" style="width:100%">
                   <f:selectItems value="#{dtEditView.tab1cols2}" var="color" itemLabel="#{color}" itemValue="#{color}" />
               </h:selectOneMenu>
           </f:facet>
       </p:cellEditor>
   </p:column>


   </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? There is no commandButton in there. And if you are new, start with a simple example without cellediting

Comment: I'm confused: You're having problem reading data and feeding the table (as your tittle suggests), or you're fetching them but you don't know how to trigger a database update on cell edit? Also, what lib are you using for persistence? Can you please make your question more clear ?

Comment: Thank you BalsuC ..needed to iterate through Bean class as suggested in this post - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151825/iterating-through-the-datatable-from-the-bean                 thank you all for your response